# Is there way in Oracle apex to validate email for User Registration

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am setting Up an Oracle Apex Application with apex 18.2.

I want to Implement User Registration process via email verification , like if User Sign up from the Application the system will generate an email with verification link and if user click on the link user will be registered to sign in to Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if Oracle supports this out of the box but you can always create a custom process for this.

You'll probably need a custom authentication function, custom users and unverified users table. Something like:

```
-- This table stores user information.
create table users_tbl ( 
  id number generated always as identity
, username varchar2(30)
, password varchar2(100)
, email_address varchar2(100)
-- etc
);

-- This table stores temporary/unverified user data.
create table unverified_users_tbl ( 
  id number generated always as identity
, username varchar2(30)
, password varchar2(100)
, email_address varchar2(100)
, verification_code varchar2(100) -- you can use sys_guid() function to generate code. also make this unique.
, expiration_date date -- you can set when the verification_code expires
, verified_flag varchar2(1) -- Y/N
-- etc
);
```

Then create a public page form for user registration which inserts data to the custom unverified_users_tbl and sends an email with a verification link. Probably better to use a procedure to do both. Something like:

Let's assume the following:

Page 1 -> Registration page (Public)
 - Has all the necessary fields for User registration.

Page 2 -> Verification page (Public)
 - Has field P2_VERIFICATION_CODE
 - Has Page On Load Process to verify the code.

Here are some ideas for the procedures:

```
create procedure register ( p_username in varchar2
                          , p_password in varchar2
                          , p_email_address in varchar2 )
is
  l_verification_code varchar2(100);
  l_subject varchar2(100);
  l_message varchar2(4000);
begin
  insert
    into unverified_users_tbl ( username
                              , password
                              , verification_code
                              , expiration_date )
  values ( p_username
         , encrypt(p_password) -- encrypt password here.
         , sys_guid()
         , sysdate + 1 -- expires after 24 hours )
  returning verification_code 
    into l_verification_code;

  l_subject := 'Verify your account';
  l_message := 'Verify your account by clicking this link. http://your-apex-url/' || apex_util.prepare_url( p_url => 'f?p=YOU_APP_ID:2:::NO::P2_VERIFICATION_CODE:' || l_verification_code );

  -- call your send mail procedure/function here.
  send_mail ( p_email_address, p_subject, p_message );
end;
/
```

Then on your Page 2 ( Verification page ), execute a PL/SQL in an On Load page process. Something like:

```
begin
  if ( verify_code ( :P2_VERIFICATION_CODE ) = true ) then
    -- display verified message
  else
    -- display error message
  end if;
end;
/

-- returns true if verified otherwise returns false
create function verify_code ( p_verification_code ) return boolean
is
begin
  -- check if code exists and not expired.
  update unverified_users_tbl
     set verified_flag = 'Y'
   where verification_code = p_verification_code
     and expiration_date >= sysdate;

  -- sql%rowcount will return the number of records affected in the update statement above.
  -- should not return more than 1 otherwise something went wrong here.
  if ( sql%rowcount = 1 ) then
    -- we're here because we successfully verified the code
    -- copy the record to the users_tbl
    insert
      into users_tbl ( username
                     , password
                     , email_address
                     -- etc
                     )
    select username
         , password
         , email_address
         -- etc
      from unverified_users_tbl
     where verification_code = p_verification_code;

    commit;

    return true;

  else
    -- we're here because the verification_code is either invalid or expired.
    return false;
  end if;

end;
/
```

Your authentication function should validate against your custom users_tbl.

You can refer to [this](http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2017/08/create-custom-authentication-and.html) for custom authentication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ank , really its helpful

Answer (score -2):

Step 1) create validation on item let Suppose P1_EMAIL.

STEP 2) SELECT ITEM MATCHES REGULAR EXPRESSION UNDER VALIDATION SECTION .PUT THIS CODE IN REGULAR EXPRESSION:

```
/^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?@[a-z][a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?$/
```

Comment: I am not sure this answer is for this question.